# Amazon S3 presigned url - Invalidate manually or one time upload

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using S3 to accept direct uploads from the user to S3. Therefore I will be using pre-signed urls.

After successful upload, AWS Lambda will make sure that the file upload is an image, and then the client will tell my server that he has finished uploading.

Then my server will check if that file exists in S3 (if Lambda detects an invalid image, it deletes it). If it does, then the rest of the application logic will follow.

However, there is a loophole in this mechanism. A user can use the same url to upload a malicious file after telling my server that he has finished uploading (and initially passing a valid file).

Lambda will still delete the file, but now my server will think that a file exists whereas it actually does not.

Is there any way to generate a one-time upload pre-signed url, or is it possible to forcefully invalidate a url that was generated but has not yet expired?

Comment: Couldn't you have Lambda move the valid files somewhere else for the server to act on?

Comment: What does somewhere else mean? If my server has to download the file from s3, what I want to achieve will be void. I don't want my server to incur any bandwidth for file IO

Comment: Well, if the file gets uploaded to `uploads/123.png`, have Lambda move it to `received/123.png` using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingREST.html. A subsequent re-use of the signed URL will put it in `uploads` again, but your server'll be checking `received` for the valid file, so the malicious user fails.

Comment: wow, simple and elegant.thanks a ton

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)

Comment: I know I'm a bit late here, but you ought to add a Lifecycle Policy (to delete files after X days) to your uploads key prefix with this method, since a user could upload a file and never tell you they've finished / upload a different one while the URL is still valid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turning this into an answer...

Once a file is uploaded, have Lambda move it (using the [Copy Object API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingREST.html)), i.e. from `uploads/123.png` to `received/123.png` or something similar.

If a malicious user attempts to re-use the signed URL, it'll go to `uploads/123.png`. Worst-case, Lambda checks it again and rejects the new file. Since your server's looking in `received/` instead of `uploads/` for files to process, we've rendered things safe.

Comment: There's a timing issue though; there's a window before the lamda executes.

Comment: I feel this should be supported as S3 feature rather than work around.  One time upload / download url for S3 object using pre signing.

Comment: This will not work. As when you upload to S3 it always creates the folder if not exists.

Comment: @iAviator That doesn't matter. That's the point of this answer. The pre-signed URL only allows the user to upload to `uploads`, not `received`, so the server knows to ignore the file if it has already been received and processed.

Comment: @ceejayoz let me explain a scenario in which it fails. I have lambda function which renames and uploads the key 1/upload/abc.json to S3. Now user generates a signed url and the lambda renames the key to 1/received/abc.json on S3. Now when a new signed url is used to upload a file it will create 1/upload/abc.json again on S3.  So the whole point here is that the fileKey is generated at run time when we create the signed url. So every time user upload file to signed url the key will be created on S3 and the rename will also be done everytime on s3. As a result the server will trigger always.

Comment: @iAviator No, because the Lambda script should be set up to check for the existence of `received/abc.json`. If it already exists, it should refuse to re-process the duplicate `upload/abc.json`.

Answer (score 20):

A **pre-signed URL** expires at a set date/time. It is **not possible** to create a one-time use pre-signed URL.

It is also not possible to invalidate a pre-signed URL. However, the pre-signed URL **uses permissions from the Access Key** that is referenced by the pre-signed URL. If permissions are removed from the User linked to the Access Key, then the pre-signed URL will not work.