# One time upload presigned URL

Tags: aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

I'm using a python lambda to generate a pre-signed URL using boto3

s3.generate_presigned_url("put_object", Params={"Bucket": bucket_name, "Key": file_name, 'ContentType': 'application/octet-stream'}, ExpiresIn=expire_time, HttpMethod='PUT')

Is there a way to generate a one time upload URL? After the first time upload, URL should be invalidated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon S3 presigned url - Invalidate manually or one time upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783108/amazon-s3-presigned-url-invalidate-manually-or-one-time-upload)